# How to correctly append the output to an empty list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, function

I am looking for words in my chosen text files.

```
def cash_sum(self):
    with open(self.infile.name, "r") as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if re.search("AMOUNT", line):
            x = []
            x.append(line[26:29])
            print(x)
```

I have this output:

```
['100']
['100']
['100']
```

And I want to add them so I can have sum of all amounts from this file.

Any advices?

Comment: Have you tried to define ``x`` before your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the sum...

```py
 def cash_sum(self):

    with open(self.infile.name, 'r') as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines()

    totalAmount = 0

    for line in lines:

        if re.search("AMOUNT", line):

            totalAmount += float(line[26:29])
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `x` outside the line-iterating loop.

Also, you don't need to `readlines()` separately...

```
def cash_sum(self):
    x = []
    with open(self.infile.name, "r") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            if re.search("AMOUNT", line):
                x.append(line[26:29])
                # or cast to int before appending:
                # x.append(int(line[26:29]))
    return x
```

Comment: OP suggests they want to sum, so maybe `int(line[26:29])`

Comment: Good point, @DeepSpace – added that in :)

Comment: One more comment. :) Using a regular expression is overkill here. A simple `if 'AMOUNT' in line:` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd recommend is casting that value to a float. I say float instead of int just in case you have a decimal point. For example, float('100') == 100.0 . Once you have that, you should be able to then add them up as you would normal numbers.

Comment: You missed the real problem : the list created in the loop

Comment: Even if you did that correctly, you're still not able to add string values, unless the desired effect is '100100100'.

Comment: Didn't say at all that what you mentionned was incorrect or whatever, just that is was insufficient. So a hafl answer isn't good, no matter the half part you chosse

Answer (score 0):

You have redefined `x` inside your loop, so every time your loop iterates, it resets x to and empty list. Try the following:

```
def cash_sum(self):
    with open(self.infile.name, "r") as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines()
    x = [] # That way x is defined outside the loop
    for line in lines:
        if re.search("AMOUNT", line):
            x.append(line[26:29])
            print(x)
    # And if you want to add each item in the list...
    num = float(0)
    for number in x:
        num = num + float(number)
    return num
```